# Bind an event handler to multiple elements jQuery?

Tags: events, jquery

I've done some experimenting, but can't seem to successfully bind one event handler to multiple elements using jQuery. Here's what I've tried:

```
$('selector1', 'selector2').bind('click', function() {
        $('someSelector').removeClass('coolClass'); 
});
```

I've tested all my selectors, and they are all valid.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so, can I do it with `.live()` as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To clarify let us extract the `selector` string into a variable:

```
var selector = ['selector1', 'selector2'];
```

the above is similar to what you have written.

```
var selector = 'selector1, selector2';
```

this is the correct way to use the interface. Note that it is a comma separated list of selector in a single string.

```
$('selector1, selector2').bind(...)
```

Comment: Took me a while to realize `'selector1, selector2'` is a single string in the answer..