# Multiple Select Options same validation

Tags: jquery

I have multiple select options but same validation - alert to say "Please select an option"

It works this way. http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/p8j2v/5/ Is there a way to shorten this ? I was thinking along these lines but I am going wrong somewhere..;o(( Can you help please ?

```
function select_option() {
  if ($("#european")[0].selectedIndex <= 0 || $("#japanese")[0].selectedIndex <= 0  || $("#american")[0].selectedIndex <= 0 {
    alert("Please choose a car"); 
    } ;
$("#assign-euro").live("click",select_option);
$("#assign-jpn").live("click",select_option);
$("#assign-american").live("click",select_option);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind an event handler to multiple elements jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793062/bind-an-event-handler-to-multiple-elements-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple selectors in jQuery separated by a comma, such that:

```
$("#assign-euro, #assign-jpn, #assign-american").on("click", select_option);
```

Note that I changed the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) call to [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/); your version of jQuery maybe be old and still expose this method, but it has since been marked first obsolete and then removed entirely from the library, with future versions recommending use of `on` or a delegate.

For reference:

> **As of jQuery 1.7**, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. We are using an older version of jquery hence using "live". Yes, we can use multiple selectors separated by a comma. The problem is the if statement.

Comment: Then your question title is misleading, and your question body does nothing to clear up the discrepancy. It's also largely a non-issue: these things are all checking the same thing, so check `$(this)`.

Comment: Sorry didnt want to confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following approach:

```
$('select').blur(function(){
    var self = this;
    if (!self.value.length) {
        alert('Please choose a ' + self.id + ' car.');
        $(self).focus();
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p8j2v/6/).

Or the following:

```
function enforceSelection () {
    var self = this,
        nationality = self.id;
    if (this.value.length === 0) {
        alert('Please choose a ' + nationality + ' car.');
        $(self).focus();
    }
}

$('#european, #japanese, #american').on('blur', enforceSelection);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p8j2v/10/).

Note that `on()` is supported in jQuery 1.7.2 (used in the Fiddle to which you linked, if you're using an *older* version of jQuery then please update the question, and the Fiddle therein, to show the version you're using).

Given the additional information provided (in the comments, below):

> ...the alert should happen only when the respective buttons are clicked as there are other links on the page.

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('button[id^="assign"]').click(function(){
    var id = this.id.replace(/assign-/,'');
    if ($('#' + id).val().length === 0) {
        alert('Please choose a ' + id + ' car.');
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p8j2v/14/).

Note that I've changed the `id`s of the first two button elements to so that the latter part of their `id` (following the hyphen) matches the `id` of the element to which the `button` itself relates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the alert should happen only when the respective buttons are clicked as there are other links on the page. After selecting "Please Select" and clicking on the other links the alert shows. Update the fiddle.

Comment: @19eggs: I've edited, and added a further snippet of code to, the answer. I *think* this does as you require?

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it by doing (I also replaced `live` with `on`, as `live` is now deprecated):

```
$("#assign-euro, #assign-jpn, #assign-american").on("click", function () {
    carValidate($(this).parent().prevAll("select"));
});

function carValidate(list) {
    if (list.val() == "") {
        alert("Please choose a car");
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8j2v/8/)

Comment: looks like your solution works..will test it later and come back to you.

Comment: Hi! Mattytommo, Your above solution works but when I put it in the actual code it fails..Updated fiddle  jsfiddle.net/19eggs/p8j2v/13 with the real code..would you mind if you take a look. Thanks

Comment: @19eggs I've made it work with your code, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p8j2v/17/

Comment: @mattytommo..Looks like the code does not work if it is enclosed in a table http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/3jJpZ/1/  If I replace <table class="task-table"> with <div> It works..any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this edit (look at the updated button IDs) (http://jsfiddle.net/mynetx/p8j2v/9/):

```html
<select id="european">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br/>

<p><button id="assign-european">Assign European Cars</button> </p>
<br/><br/>

<select id="japanese">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
  <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
  <option value="mitsubihi">Mitsubishi</option>
  <option value="honda">Honda</option>
</select>
<br/> 
<p><button id="assign-japanese">Assign Japanese Cars</button> </p>
<br /><br />
<select id="american">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="jeep">Jeep</option>
  <option value="ford">Ford</option>
  <option value="chrysler">Chrysler</option>
  <option value="chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
</select>
<p><button id="assign-american">Assign American Cars</button> </p>
```

```js
$("button[id^=assign-]").on("click", function () {
    if ($("select#" + $(this).prop("id").substring(7))[0].selectedIndex === 0) {
        alert("Please choose a car");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi! Your solution works but just been told that it does not use button uses input and the id are weird...eg id="ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.5." Update the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/p8j2v/13/

Comment: Do the ids of the button inputs correlate somehow to the select box ids or names?

Comment: No they don't. They are different. Updated fiddle  jsfiddle.net/19eggs/p8j2v/13